# Reverse SSH connection (over eth1) gets dropped when eth0 receives an IP

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, ssh

I have a linux device that makes a reverse SSH tunnel over a 4g dongle (eth1) to an amazon server.
This allows me to connect on the device after connecting to the amazon server.

As soon as I insert an ethernet cable, I execute 'dhclient eth0'. Unfortunately, as soon as  the IP is given to the eth0 interface, my ssh connection is killed.

When I physically check the device, the device succesfully managed to receive 2 ip's on both interfaces.

How do I keep my autossh connection alive?

Comment: I guess the new connection alters the routing table. Possibly your problem is like this one: [Change the default route without affecting existing TCP connections](https://superuser.com/q/510630/432690). Note the answer there is 10 years old (and therefore I'm not marking your question as duplicate), [nowadays `ip route` is encouraged](https://superuser.com/a/735378/432690).

Comment: I cant even see the route to my amazon server if I check netstat -nr or route -n